# Should I USE standard deviation OR standard error for an estimate of confidence-interval?

Tags: confidence-interval, estimation, standard-error

I am trying to build confidence interval for mean of a metrics. To build confidence interval whether standard error or standard deviation should be used ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the standard error $SE$ (not the standard deviation $s$) to calculate confidence intervals.

The confidence interval for a population mean is equal to:

$$CI=\bar{X} \pm t_{crit}\times SE_{\bar{X}}$$

$$SE_{\bar{X}}= \frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}$$
where $\bar{X}$ is the sample mean and $n$ is the sample size.
The assumption for the formula is standard normal distribution.

Comment: It is really the population mean that you determine confidence intervals for.  In your example you have a confidence interval centered at the sample mean and the interval is exact only for iid normals.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Let assume the case - I have access to entire population. In this case is it meaningful to use standard deviation ? (inferential vs descriptive)

Comment: If you have access to the population parameter, there is no need for estimation using sample statistics. You can just present the population mean and standard deviation.

Comment: If by access to the entire population you mean that you have say a normal distribution with the mean and variance known you don't have an inference problem.  For a confidence interval to make sense you would possibly know the variance but not the mean.  Then the true standard deviation replaces the sample mean and the t crit with the zcrit but the standard error is still used and the square root of n remains in the denominator.

Comment: @JeffreyGirard I see you changed t_crit in your answer to z_crit. I had no objection to assuming normality  With the change you need to assume large n and enough central moments for the central limit theorem to apply is you want to make the population distribution more general. Here I am stating the conditions for the Lyapunov version of the central limit theorem.

Comment: @MichaelChernick Someone else edited my answer to change to z_crit. I agree that t_crit is more appropriate with a smaller n. I have changed it back.

Comment: @JeffreyGirard  At least you know that I didn't edit it!